# STM32 M4 not running after J-Link and J-Flash

Tags: stm32, cortex-m4, j-link

I'm temporarily using a J-Link Pro as a production programmer for a STM32L4R9.

I've modified the scripts found here https://wiki.segger.com/ST_STM32 to unlock, then lock and set the option bits for BOR and ROP levels.  Everything works, except that I have to completely power cycle the device before it will boot.  It completely ignores the NRST and NJTRST pin.

Is it possible to make this work, or is there some non obvious limitation preventing this?  Or perhaps something I'm missing otherwise?

Edit: I have a hardware reset button connected to nReset so I know its ignoring the NRST pin.

Here is my j-flash script

```
  AppVersion = 76803
  FileVersion = 2
[GENERAL]
  aATEModuleSel[24] = 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
  ConnectMode = 0
  CurrentFile = "A2630-boot THUMB Release\A2630-boot.hex"
  DataFileSAddr = 0x00000000
  GUIMode = 0
  HostName = ""
  TargetIF = 1
  USBPort = 0
  USBSerialNo = 0x00000000
  UseATEModuleSelection = 0
[JTAG]
  IRLen = 0
  MultipleTargets = 0
  NumDevices = 0
  Speed0 = 4000
  Speed1 = 4000
  TAP_Number = 0
  UseAdaptive0 = 0
  UseAdaptive1 = 0
  UseMaxSpeed0 = 0
  UseMaxSpeed1 = 0
[CPU]
  NumInitSteps = 29
  InitStep0_Action = "Read 32bit"
  InitStep0_Value0 = 0xE0042008
  InitStep0_Value1 = 0x00000000
  InitStep0_Comment = ""
  InitStep1_Action = "Var OR"
  InitStep1_Value0 = 0x00000000
  InitStep1_Value1 = 0x00001800
  InitStep1_Comment = ""
  InitStep2_Action = "Var Write 32bit"
  InitStep2_Value0 = 0xE0042008
  InitStep2_Value1 = 0x00000000
  InitStep2_Comment = "Set bit 11 and bit 12 in order to disable independend and window watchdog"
  InitStep3_Action = "Reset"
  InitStep3_Value0 = 0x00000000
  InitStep3_Value1 = 0x00000005
  InitStep3_Comment = "Reset and halt target"
  InitStep4_Action = "Read 32bit"
  InitStep4_Value0 = 0x40022020
  InitStep4_Value1 = 0x00000000
  InitStep4_Comment = ""
  InitStep5_Action = "Var AND"
  InitStep5_Value0 = 0x00000000
  InitStep5_Value1 = 0x000000FF
  InitStep5_Comment = ""
  InitStep6_Action = "Var XOR"
  InitStep6_Value0 = 0x00000000
  InitStep6_Value1 = 0x000000AA
  InitStep6_Comment = ""
  InitStep7_Action = "Var BEQ"
  InitStep7_Value0 = 0x0000001C
  InitStep7_Value1 = 0x00000000
  InitStep7_Comment = "ROP Level 0 is set, unlock not necessary"
  InitStep8_Action = "Write 32bit"
  InitStep8_Value0 = 0x40022008
  InitStep8_Value1 = 0x45670123
  InitStep8_Comment = "Unlock FLASH_CR Key1"
  InitStep9_Action = "Write 32bit"
  InitStep9_Value0 = 0x40022008
  InitStep9_Value1 = 0xCDEF89AB
  InitStep9_Comment = "Unlock FLASH_CR Key2"
  InitStep10_Action = "Write 32bit"
  InitStep10_Value0 = 0x4002200C
  InitStep10_Value1 = 0x08192A3B
  InitStep10_Comment = "Unlock FLASH_OPTR Key1"
  InitStep11_Action = "Write 32bit"
  InitStep11_Value0 = 0x4002200C
  InitStep11_Value1 = 0x4C5D6E7F
  InitStep11_Comment = "Unlock FLASH_OPTR Key2"
  InitStep12_Action = "Write 32bit"
  InitStep12_Value0 = 0x40022010
  InitStep12_Value1 = 0x0000C1FB
  InitStep12_Comment = "Clear all error bits in the FLASH_SR"
  InitStep13_Action = "Read 32bit"
  InitStep13_Value0 = 0x40022020
  InitStep13_Value1 = 0x00000000
  InitStep13_Comment = ""
  InitStep14_Action = "Var AND"
  InitStep14_Value0 = 0x00000000
  InitStep14_Value1 = 0xFFFFFF00
  InitStep14_Comment = ""
  InitStep15_Action = "Var OR"
  InitStep15_Value0 = 0x00000000
  InitStep15_Value1 = 0x000000AA
  InitStep15_Comment = ""
  InitStep16_Action = "Var Write 32bit"
  InitStep16_Value0 = 0x40022020
  InitStep16_Value1 = 0x00000000
  InitStep16_Comment = ""
  InitStep17_Action = "Read 32bit"
  InitStep17_Value0 = 0x40022014
  InitStep17_Value1 = 0x00000000
  InitStep17_Comment = ""
  InitStep18_Action = "Var OR"
  InitStep18_Value0 = 0x00000000
  InitStep18_Value1 = 0x00020000
  InitStep18_Comment = ""
  InitStep19_Action = "Var Write 32bit"
  InitStep19_Value0 = 0x40022014
  InitStep19_Value1 = 0x00000000
  InitStep19_Comment = "Set OPTSTRT bit, bit 17 in FLASH_CR"
  InitStep20_Action = "Delay"
  InitStep20_Value0 = 0x00000000
  InitStep20_Value1 = 0x00000064
  InitStep20_Comment = ""
  InitStep21_Action = "Read 32bit"
  InitStep21_Value0 = 0x40022014
  InitStep21_Value1 = 0x00000000
  InitStep21_Comment = ""
  InitStep22_Action = "Var AND"
  InitStep22_Value0 = 0x00000000
  InitStep22_Value1 = 0x00010000
  InitStep22_Comment = ""
  InitStep23_Action = "Var BNE"
  InitStep23_Value0 = 0x00000014
  InitStep23_Value1 = 0x00000000
  InitStep23_Comment = "Wait for busy bit to clear, bit 16 of FLASH_CR"
  InitStep24_Action = "Read 32bit"
  InitStep24_Value0 = 0x40022014
  InitStep24_Value1 = 0x00000000
  InitStep24_Comment = ""
  InitStep25_Action = "Var OR"
  InitStep25_Value0 = 0x00000000
  InitStep25_Value1 = 0x08000000
  InitStep25_Comment = ""
  InitStep26_Action = "Var Write 32bit"
  InitStep26_Value0 = 0x40022014
  InitStep26_Value1 = 0x00000000
  InitStep26_Comment = "Set OBL_LAUNCH bit, bit 27 of FLASH_CR"
  InitStep27_Action = "Delay"
  InitStep27_Value0 = 0x00000000
  InitStep27_Value1 = 0x0000012C
  InitStep27_Comment = "Device is not responsive, therefore we wait some time here and reset."
  InitStep28_Action = "Reset"
  InitStep28_Value0 = 0x00000000
  InitStep28_Value1 = 0x00000000
  InitStep28_Comment = ""
  NumExitSteps = 14
  ExitStep0_Action = "Write 32bit"
  ExitStep0_Value0 = 0x40022008
  ExitStep0_Value1 = 0x45670123
  ExitStep0_Comment = "Unlock FLASH_CR "
  ExitStep1_Action = "Write 32bit"
  ExitStep1_Value0 = 0x40022008
  ExitStep1_Value1 = 0xCDEF89AB
  ExitStep1_Comment = ""
  ExitStep2_Action = "Write 32bit"
  ExitStep2_Value0 = 0x4002200C
  ExitStep2_Value1 = 0x08192A3B
  ExitStep2_Comment = "Unlock FLASH_OPTR"
  ExitStep3_Action = "Write 32bit"
  ExitStep3_Value0 = 0x4002200C
  ExitStep3_Value1 = 0x4C5D6E7F
  ExitStep3_Comment = ""
  ExitStep4_Action = "Write 32bit"
  ExitStep4_Value0 = 0x40022010
  ExitStep4_Value1 = 0x0000C1FB
  ExitStep4_Comment = "Clear all error bits in FLASH_SR"
  ExitStep5_Action = "Delay"
  ExitStep5_Value0 = 0x00000000
  ExitStep5_Value1 = 0x00000001
  ExitStep5_Comment = ""
  ExitStep6_Action = "Write 8bit"
  ExitStep6_Value0 = 0x40022020
  ExitStep6_Value1 = 0x000000BB
  ExitStep6_Comment = "Set ROP to Level 1. 0xAA = Level 0; 0xCC = Level 2"
  ExitStep7_Action = "Write 8bit"
  ExitStep7_Value0 = 0x40022021
  ExitStep7_Value1 = 0x000000FA
  ExitStep7_Comment = "Set BOR to level 2"
  ExitStep8_Action = "Delay"
  ExitStep8_Value0 = 0x00000000
  ExitStep8_Value1 = 0x00000001
  ExitStep8_Comment = ""
  ExitStep9_Action = "Write 8bit"
  ExitStep9_Value0 = 0x40022016
  ExitStep9_Value1 = 0x00000002
  ExitStep9_Comment = "Set OPTSTRT bit"
  ExitStep10_Action = "Delay"
  ExitStep10_Value0 = 0x00000000
  ExitStep10_Value1 = 0x00000001
  ExitStep10_Comment = ""
  ExitStep11_Action = "Write 8bit"
  ExitStep11_Value0 = 0x40022017
  ExitStep11_Value1 = 0x00000008
  ExitStep11_Comment = "Set OBL_LAUNCH bit"
  ExitStep12_Action = "Delay"
  ExitStep12_Value0 = 0x00000000
  ExitStep12_Value1 = 0x0000012C
  ExitStep12_Comment = "Not possible to read memory here, therfore fixed delay."
  ExitStep13_Action = "Reset"
  ExitStep13_Value0 = 0x00000000
  ExitStep13_Value1 = 0x00000000
  ExitStep13_Comment = ""
  UseScriptFile = 0
  ScriptFile = ""
  UseRAM = 1
  RAMAddr = 0x20000000
  RAMSize = 0x00008000
  CheckCoreID = 1
  CoreID = 0x4BA00477
  CoreIDMask = 0x0F000FFF
  UseAutoSpeed = 0x00000001
  ClockSpeed = 0x00000000
  EndianMode = 0
  ChipName = "ST STM32L4R9ZG"
[FLASH]
  NumBanks = 2
[FLASH0]
  aRangeSel[1] = 0-255
  BankName = "Internal flash"
  BankSelMode = 1
  BaseAddr = 0x08000000
[FLASH1]
  BankName = "External QSPI flash"
  BaseAddr = 0x90000000
[PRODUCTION]
  AutoPerformsDisconnect = 1
  AutoPerformsErase = 1
  AutoPerformsProgram = 1
  AutoPerformsSecure = 0
  AutoPerformsStartApp = 1
  AutoPerformsUnsecure = 0
  AutoPerformsVerify = 1
  EnableFixedVTref = 0
  EnableTargetPower = 0
  EraseType = 1
  FixedVTref = 0x00000CE4
  MonitorVTref = 0
  MonitorVTrefMax = 0x0000157C
  MonitorVTrefMin = 0x000003E8
  OverrideTimeouts = 0
  ProgramSN = 0
  SerialFile = ""
  SNAddr = 0x00000000
  SNInc = 0x00000001
  SNLen = 0x00000004
  SNListFile = ""
  SNValue = 0x00000001
  StartAppType = 1
  TargetPowerDelay = 0x00000014
  TimeoutErase = 0x00003A98
  TimeoutProgram = 0x00002710
  TimeoutVerify = 0x00002710
  VerifyType = 1
[PERFORMANCE]
  DisableSkipBlankDataOnProgram = 0x00000000
  PerfromBlankCheckPriorEraseChip = 0x00000001
  PerfromBlankCheckPriorEraseSelectedSectors = 0x00000001
```

Comment: Doesn't NJTRST only reset the JTAG interface? Shouldn't you be toggling NRST instead to reset the entire MCU?

Comment: I have them tied together. I updated the question.

Comment: Which pin on the J-Link are you driving them with - nTRST (pin-3) or RESET (pin-15)?

Comment: I'm using this adapter, so I think its pin 15 https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/accessories/adapters/9-pin-cortex-m-adapter/ Note that I have a hardware reset pin connected to this circuit, this is how I know for sure its ignoring the NRST.